# Adjacent JSX elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I will be very happy if you can help me. I am making react native expo app. I have code that displays information from the database. When I inserted the code to add an image, I had an error, why?

Error:
Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...? (79:12)

```html
  <View>



        <ListView

          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}

          renderSeparator= {this.ListViewItemSeparator}

          renderRow={(rowData) =>


            <Image
         source={require('../assets/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg')}
       />

            <Text
                      onPress={() => {
                        /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
                          otherParam: rowData.article_title,
                        });
                      }}
                    >{rowData.article_title}</Text>

      }



        />

      </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<View>
  <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderSeparator={this.ListViewItemSeparator}
    renderRow={rowData => (
      <>
        <Image
          source={require("../assets/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg")}
        />
        <Text
          onPress={() => {
            /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
            this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", {
              otherParam: rowData.article_title,
            });
          }}
        >
          {rowData.article_title}
        </Text>
      </>
    )}
  />
</View>;
```

This issue is that you're rendering in your expression two components that are on the same level. so you must have a JSX fragment or another div as a single parent in your `return` statement of the `renderRow`.. I believe the above code should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap the elements with a Fragment element. The reason why is `ListView` requires one element to work off of for a "row". You can simulate this with the fragment :)

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Image />
  <Text />
</React.Fragment>
```

theres some nice syntax for fragments if your compiler supports it

```
<>
</>
```

To apply it to your code

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderSeparator={this.ListViewItemSeparator}
  renderRow={rowData => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Image
        source={require("../assets/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg")}
      />
      <Text
        onPress={() => {
          /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", {
            otherParam: rowData.article_title,
          });
        }}
      >
        {rowData.article_title}
      </Text>
    </ React.Fragment>
  )}
/>
```